# Whats difference between function which returns void and Function type?

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces;

```
interface A {
 func: () => void;
} 

interface B {
 func: Function;
}
```

What's the difference between `A` and `B` interfaces?

Comment: `() => void` describes a function that takes no parameters and returns a value that should not be used. `Function` describes any function (essentially).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using `Function` type isn’t very good idea, even TS linter warn you that this is dangerous because you don’t provide scheme of function:

Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value.
It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs.
It also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with `new`.
If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape.

So better use something like

```
interface A {
  func: (a: string) => number;
}
```

Btw for void function you could also use `VoidFunction` type instead of `() => void;`